# What is the usage of `_stopwatch_token` in symfony request?

Tags: php, symfony

When I get `dump($request->attributes->all());` in a controller out of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`, I can see that this attribute **`_stopwatch_token`** in it which is comes from [this file](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.3/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php#LL33C56-L33C72).

What are the possible applications for this attribute, and does it remain accessible in the production environment or is it limited to local usage when debug mode is active?